# ERROR when i run pip install mssql-django or pip install pyodbc

Tags: django, pyodbc, pymssql

Getting below error but got the solution also, you just do the following steps

1. Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc)
2. Sownload suitable '".whl"' file (Make sure you choose the correct whl file. For example: If you are using Python 2.7 on a 64-bit machine choose '''pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl'''.)
3. run '''pip install pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl''' and try again

**This was the error**

Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\x\x\x\x\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\xxxx\x\x\Local\Temp\pip-install-8j3hztgx\pyodbc_b5b6921fa34f4725a66d9248ff07177c\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8j3hztgx\pyodbc_b5b6921fa34f4725a66d9248ff07177c\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e9qbaui4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\pyodbc'
cwd: C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8j3hztgx\pyodbc_b5b6921fa34f4725a66d9248ff07177c
Complete output (12 lines):
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.32 -IC:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um /EHsc /T    C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8j3hztgx\pyodbc_b5b6921fa34f4725a66d9248ff07177c\src\pyodbc.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exi    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools,
tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8j3hztgx\pyodbc_b5b6921fa34f4725a66d9248ff07177c\setup.py'"'"'; __file_n'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e9qbaui4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\pyodbc' Che

Answer (score 0):

got the solution, you just do the following steps

Go to

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc)

Download the suitable '".whl"' file (Make sure you choose the correct whl file. For example: If you are using Python 3.10 on a 64-bit machine choose '''pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl'''.)

run

```
pip install pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```